# Divide window values by a reference row

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to have some guidance or help to address the following problem:

I have the following data in a Spark Data frame.
I would like to create a window of n days preceding a succeeding a reference record and then calculate a division using reference values with the values in the window.
However I have not figured out how to do this kind of operation, everything that I find is just mean, count or sum operations in the window.

Original data looks like this:

```
| symbol_id | date       | close    | is_reference |
|----------|------------|----------|--------------|
| XXXX     | 2000-01-19 | 809.9644 | FALSE        |
| XXXX     | 2000-01-20 | 784.274  | FALSE        |
| XXXX     | 2000-01-21 | 774.2831 | FALSE        |
| XXXX     | 2000-01-24 | 760.0106 | FALSE        |
| XXXX     | 2000-01-25 | 750.7335 | FALSE        |
| XXXX     | 2000-01-26 | 750.7335 | TRUE         |
| XXXX     | 2000-01-27 | 742.17   | FALSE        |
| XXXX     | 2000-01-28 | 749.3063 | FALSE        |
| XXXX     | 2000-01-31 | 750.02   | FALSE        |
| XXXX     | 2000-02-01 | 762.8653 | FALSE        |
| XXXX     | 2000-02-02 | 749.3063 | FALSE        |
```

Expected output looks like this:

```
| symbol_id | date       | close    | is_reference | reference_change  |
|----------|------------|----------|--------------|-------------------|
| XXXX     | 2000-01-19 | 809.9644 | FALSE        | 1.07889737170381  |
| XXXX     | 2000-01-20 | 784.274  | FALSE        | 1.04467697258748  |
| XXXX     | 2000-01-21 | 774.2831 | FALSE        | 1.03136878799201  |
| XXXX     | 2000-01-24 | 760.0106 | FALSE        | 1.0123573811479   |
| XXXX     | 2000-01-25 | 750.7335 | FALSE        | 1                 |
| XXXX     | 2000-01-26 | 750.7335 | TRUE         | 1                 |
| XXXX     | 2000-01-27 | 742.17   | FALSE        | 0.988593155893536 |
| XXXX     | 2000-01-28 | 749.3063 | FALSE        | 0.99809892591712  |
| XXXX     | 2000-01-31 | 750.02   | FALSE        | 0.999049596161621 |
| XXXX     | 2000-02-01 | 762.8653 | FALSE        | 1.01615992892285  |
| XXXX     | 2000-02-02 | 749.3063 | FALSE        | 0.99809892591712  |
```

I'm currently partition by symbol_id using the following snippet:

```scala
val window = Window.partitionBy(SYMBOL_ID)
    .orderBy(col(DATE).desc)
    .rowsBetween(5,0) // RangeBetween looks better but i just trying with rowsBetween for now
```

And trying to do something like this on `reference_change` column.

```scala
df
    .withColumn("close_movement", $"close"/lit(col("close")
    .where(col("is_reference") === true)).over(window)) // This command is wrong but its the most similar to thoughts in my mind.
```

So at the end I will be using the `close` `WHERE` `is_reference = true` divide by the `close` on the windows like the `reference_change` column we have on the expected output.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use a simple join:

```
val ref = df.filter($"is_reference")
df.join(ref, df.col("symbol_id") === ref.col("symbol_id") &&
             abs(date_diff(df.col("date"), ref.col("date"))) <= 5)
  .select(df.col("symbol_id"), df.col("date"), df.col("close"), df.col("is_reference"),
          (df.col("close") / ref.col("close")).as("reference_change"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it definitively points me in the right direction after the join I just need to aggregate (we had overlaps) and do the operations in the aggregation.
This solution works perfect with little syntax modifications on Spark Scala.